# Http GET call with header option is returning Unauthorized error

Tags: angular, http, token

I am passing access_token in the header for http.get call but I am getting UnAhuthorized 401 erorr, while with the access_token I can get the data from the API in postman.

Note: I am not using HTTP INCERCEPTOR in my project

```
 let header_object = {

 'Content-Type'       : 'application/json',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' : 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content- Type, Accept',
  'Authorization' : 'bearer ' + this.token.toString().replace(/"/g, ""),
};

  httpOptions = {headers: header_object };
  // console.log(this.token);
  console.log(httpOptions);
  })
return this.http.get<JSON>(this.baseurl, httpOptions);
```

Comment: Is your token valid?

Comment: yes the token is valid

Comment: 1. Does the same call work in postman? 2. Where are you subscribing to this *GET* call? 3. What are you trying to replace in this line `this.token.toString().replace(/"/g, "")`?

Comment: @NicholasK from Postman I am getting the result. Subscription of the GET call in the component. To remove the quotation from the token I placed toString().replace(/"/g, "")

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+ token
    });
  return this.http.get<JSON>(this.baseurl, headers);
```